# Is there a way to get function or or property in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

as an example there is an object colors.

```
colors = {
  white: '#fff',
  whiteF: (opacity=1) => `rgba(255,255,255,${opacity})`    
}
```

Is there a better way to connect them like this: If I call `colors.white` it will call hex and if I call `colors.white(.3)` it will get rgba one.

Comment: It's not possible for you to have a dictionary with same keys, the latter one will override. instead, why not make colors itself a function and you can choose to call it with empty parameters to call white or parameters to cal faded white with ternary operator maybe.

     ```function color (opacity) {
           return opacity ? `rgba(255,255,255,${opacity})` : '#fff'
     }```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a conditional inside the function should do the trick (with a default value)

```
const colors = {
  white: (opacity=1) => {
    if(opacity === 1){
      return '#fff'
    }else{
      return`rgba(255,255,255,${opacity})`
    }
  }
}

> colors.white()
'#fff'
> colors.white(.3)
'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use function which will serve as delegator to either user property or method based on paramter passed to it as follows:

```
colors = {
  white: '#fff',
  whiteF: (opacity=1) => `rgba(255,255,255,${opacity})` ,
   getColor:function(opacity){
     if(opacity)
     return this.whiteF(opacity);
     else {
         return this.white;
     }

  }
}
 console.log(colors.getColor());
 console.log(colors.getColor(0.3));
```

With this your method call will return either property or function invocation.